# After hitting the daily reputation limit, how do I tell which answers were upvoted?

Tags: support, reputation, notifications, daily-reputation-limit

The daily reputation limit is 200.  After I reach that limit, how will I know whether other answers I wrote were also upvoted or not? SO does not notify me of any additional reputation gains.  Will I get that reputation on the next day?

Comment: IIRC you can actually see the upvotes in your reputation history, they just don't contribute rep further that day.

Comment: It looks like someone decided to give you a gift. [Rep today](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o2uw8.png)

Comment: I was also thinking so.

Comment: @OAD That will probably gone tomorrow.

Comment: @Rizier123 what will gone tomorrow?

Comment: @OAD Those upvotes and the reputation that came with them. The system automatically revokes serial votes where one user votes for another several times in a row.

Comment: @OAD http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: Good news, you don't have to worry about hitting the reputation cap today. We took care of that for you.

Comment: @BradLarson thank you.

Comment: @BradLarson out of interest, how rep would be calculated if someone hits 200 from serial voting, then it gets reversed (normal time, so most probably after the rep cap resets), but he got OTHER votes after hitting 200? Will he lose the rep from serial voting and the daily rep be recalculated?

Comment: @Patrice yes. Votes that were received after the original cap are now counted, though it won't show that in your reputation tab straight away.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF! Was just out of interest, but I could see it as a possible way of gaming the system if it wasn't done the way you just said (ie serial upvoting Jon skeet EVERY day to stop him from growing rep forever :P)

Comment: Looks like more serial up-voting again in the last hour-ish http://stackoverflow.com/users/4127893/oad?tab=reputation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can still see the answers on [your reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4127893/oad?tab=reputation), and you can also see when upvotes occur.  You won't get more than 200 rep through upvotes per day, but you can at least see when someone upvoted it.

Also, votes that are made on one day don't roll over into the next, even if you've hit the cap.

Comment: it means after 12AM new reputation can be added? or after 24hours of time exceeded limit?

Comment: The limit is per-day, and that day ends at 11:59:59PM UTC, so once its midnight UTC, you'll be eligible to receive rep from upvoting.

Comment: @Makoto Someone did a serial upvoting on my questions and I got +100 rep and already hit the 200 rep, and not getting any reps on upvotes, understandable, tomorrow serial upvoting will be reversed, and today's upvotes (after hitting the cap) will be in vain, how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

> how will I know that whether other answers were also helpful or not?

Look at the reputation sub-tab of your profile page.

> will score be added on next day?

No.